# SwiftUI ObservedObject not updating view after successful login

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine, observedobject

To show my the content from my root view after successful login, I tried with `ObservedObject`, and with `EnvironmentObject`, to no avail.

E.g. as follows:

```swift
struct RootView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var loginManager: LoginManager

    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if loginManager.isLoggedIn {
                SegmentedView()
            }
            else {
                WelcomeView()
            }
        }
    }
}

class LoginManager: ObservableObject {
    
    static let shared = LoginManager()
    var cancellable = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    @Published var isLoggedIn = false

    ...
    
    func login(...) {
        ...
        // on success
        self.isLoggedIn = true
    }
```

The `LoginManager` is retained in the `SceneDelegate` and put into the environment:

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var loginManager = LoginManager.shared
    ...

    // the view passed to window.rootUiewController via UIHostingController
    let contentView = RootView().environmentObject(loginManager)
```

After logging in, it goes right back to my `WelcomeView`. What am I missing?

**EDIT**

Here is a new aspect. I have a view model for the `LoginView` to manage the data in date fields. When the login button is pressed, I call a `login()` method in this view model.

I need to two `.sink` callbacks in the view model, because I have to dismiss the loading indicator by setting a `loading` flag to false.

So I cannot call `self.isLoggedIn = true` directly because I am in the view model, not the `LoginManager`. Instead I call

```
self.loginManager.isLoggedIn = true
```

and I suspect that this line is not working.

The connection between view model and login manager is done like this

```
@ObservedObject var loginManager = LoginManager.shared
```

However, after shifting this to the `LoginManager`, I am indeed calling `self.isLoggedIn` from there. It is still not working.

I have two theses:

1. It could be that the view is not set up correctly with `Group` etc. I also tried to use `@ViewBuilder` etc, no difference.
2. It could be that somehow there are two instances of `LoginManager`, or the `RootView` somehow get's reinitialised with a new instance where `isLoggedIn` is false. But I have been creating Swift singletons like this for ages:

   static let shared = LoginManager()

and never had any problems.

As mentioned in the comments, there is another error I encountered when switching all to `@EnvironmentObject`:

> `Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type LoginManager found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for LoginManager may be missing as an ancestor of this view.: file SwiftUI, line 0`

Comment: BTW, after some debugging with breakpoints, it seems the view is re-created with the condition being `true`, and then immediately destroyed and created again with `false`.

Comment: is there anywhere else that you access LoginManager? Like does `SegmentedView` use it or change the `isLoggedIn` property?

Comment: @mginn No. There is an alternative login scenario with a token, but I am testing the username password login right now. I am noticing that I am not "dismissing" the login view which is accessed from Welcome View via Navigation Link. And that sometimes after login the view does not get recreated or updated.

Comment: Is `self.isLoggedIn = true` performed on main queue?

Comment: Yes. It is part of a Combine pipeline, where just before `.sink` I call `.receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)`. @Asperi

Comment: @Mundi, I can't reproduce this with the code you shared (with some additions to make it actually work). I think the issue is somewhere else

Comment: OK, super - would you like to share? -- Perhaps it is related to where I set this value.

Comment: @NewDev Please see my edit. I explain where I am trying to change `isLoggedIn`.

Comment: I also got this error after shifting all `@ObservedObject`s to `@EnvironmentObject`. This might be instructive: `Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type LoginManager found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for LoginManager may be missing as an ancestor of this view.: file SwiftUI, line 0`

Comment: @Mundi, not really sure what to share. It's basically what you have. I added an outer VStack in the view to add a fake "login" button that calls `login` on the view model. And I simulated async login with `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter`. That's about it

Comment: OK, thanks. Obviously, I cannot do it all in one file. It seems to be a architectural problem. It would be great to find some working example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got the error.

I assumed `.sink(receiveCompletion:`  always has an error because the template to which I was referring to it. But the completion block is called no matter what.

Unfortunately, if you insert a parameter `error in` it will never be `nil` but contain something like

```
Combine.Subscribers.Completion<module.CustomError>.finished
```

So I guess, you are not supposed to check for errors there again.